# Get the distinct custom attribute values based on current category

Tags: php, magento

I am newbie to magento. I have custom attribute fields named "author". I need to display the distinct author name based on current category .Please help me ! I got stucked with this. Currently it is displaying twice or thrice , same author name . Any help would appreciate a lot . Below is the code which is not working fine .

```
<?php
      $cat_idD = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getId();
      $loadcatID = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat_idD);
      $collection = $loadcatID ->getProductCollection();
      $collection->addAttributeToSelect('author');
      $collection->getSelect()->distinct(true);

        $authname = "";

        foreach( $collection as $product){
           $authname .="<li>";
           $authname .="<input type='radio' id='".$product->getId()."' name='author' value='".$product->getauthor()."' class='left authfilter'>";
           $authname .="<label for='".$product->getId()."' class='left'>".$product->getauthor()."</label>";
           $authname .="</li>";

        }

        echo  $authname;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should group by "author".

```
$collection->getSelect()->group('author');
```

If you want to debug the query executed :

```
$collection->getSelect()->__toString();
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: if i place the code                           $collection->getSelect()->group('author') instead of $collection->getSelect()->distinct(true) . I am getting the error  as  "There has been an error processing your request" 
"Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons." which is not working